# Как правильно использовать Dagger2?

Tags: java, android, dagger2

Нашел код и хочу разобраться как работает `Dagger2`

Вот я слепил такой простой пример и не могу понять как его соединить чтоб он работал

Есть `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Inject
protected ApiInterface apiInterface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (apiInterface == null){
        Log.e("TAG", "apiInterface == null");
    }else {
        Log.e("TAG", "apiInterface != null : " + apiInterface.value);
    }
}
}
```

Я хочу инжекнуть в переменную `apiInterface` ссылку на класс. Для этого я указываю ключевое слово `@Inject`.

Теперь, чтоб `Dagger` знал что инжекать туда я слепил вот такой класс

```
@Module
class ModelModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
ApiInterface provideApiInterface() {
    return ApiModule.getApiInterface();
}
}
```

Теперь я так понимаю `Dagger` когда увидит в `MainActivity` слово `@Inject` и тип переменной(насколько я понимаю), то он пойдет искать кто ему возвращает такой тип и найдет класс `ModelModule` в котором метод `provideApiInterface()` возвращает то что нужно `apiInterface`.

Вот кстати для ясности этот класс

```
class ApiInterface {
int value;

ApiInterface() {
    this.value = 4;
}
}
```

Но теперь, чтоб все заработало нужно указать `@Component` в котором указывается от куда брать обьекты и куда внедрять...

Но это теория, так как я не понимаю зачем это нужно... Мы и так указали уже от куда брать обьекты, а словом `@Inject` мы указываем куда внедрять... Зачем еще что то нужно?

Вот тут и есть проблема, обьясните зачем нужен `@Component` и как его составить для конкретного примера, чтоб все заработало и я мог в `MainActivity` получить число 4...

**ПРАВКА**
Вот я слепил вот такой компонент

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ModelModule.class})
interface AppComponent {

void inject(ApiInterface apiInterface);
}
```

В `MainActivity` я все равно получаю `null`

Где ошибка?

Comment: потому что модули могут быть разными и реализации тоже могут быть разными. Вы задаете вопрос о целях, которые преследовали разработчики библиотеки, тут их нет. Возможно вам статьи помогут вникнуть в суть. https://habrahabr.ru/post/279125/ и https://habrahabr.ru/post/279641/

Comment: @andreich Я добавил в вопрос правку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо создать AppComponent  в MainActivity

```
appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().modelModule(new ModelModule()).build();
```

и сделать `appComponent.inject(this)`

Comment: Я не могу в `MainActivity` указать `inject(this)` так как этот метод принимает `ApiInterface apiInterface` как я указал в правке...

Comment: Все разобрался)

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно, без компонента никуда, так как без него твой класс, который зашивает зависимости не понимает откуда их брать. Если ты передаёшь в компонент ссылку на себя же (например через метод inject()), то компонент просматривает твой класс, распознает все поля которые нужно заинжектить и передает запрос в нужный Module, напомню что модулей может быть несколько, которые могут иметь одинаковые возвращаемые значения, а компонент указывает именно тот, который нужен тебе в данной ситуации

Как написал комментатор выше в твоём классе нужно создать компонент и передать в метод компонента ссылку на твой класс. Необходимый код как раз написали выше